# Как проверить содержимое строчки

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, текст

Есть строчка:
String msg = "test";

Как можно проверить что там нету русских символов и нет пробелов?

Comment: Регуляркой, само собой...

Answer (score 0):

Самое правильное - разобраться с регулярными выражениями. Но если строка небольшая, можно строку разбить на char массив и проверить каждый символ по таблице ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

Вот такое решение для вас подойдет:

```
System.out.println("test".matches("[а-яА-ЯёЁ]+"));
System.out.println("тест".matches("[а-яА-ЯёЁ]+"));
```

Но имейте ввиду, что эта регулярка не примет пробелов и знаков препинаний...вы их просто можете добавить во внутрь регулярного выражения:

```
System.out.println("Я, Стеков Стек Стекович, буду завтракать".matches("[а-яА-ЯёЁ ,!]+"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Функция [String.matches](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)) требует полного совпадения строки, указанному выражению, и без дополнительных условий не проверит наличие указанных символов (например: `".*[а-яА-ЯёЁ].*"`).

Но с этим справится функция [Matcher.find](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()):

```
Pattern patternFindRu = Pattern.compile("[а-яА-ЯёЁ]");

System.out.println(patternFindRu.matcher("Test").find());       // false
System.out.println(patternFindRu.matcher("Вася").find());       // true
System.out.println(patternFindRu.matcher(" Вася").find());      // true
System.out.println(patternFindRu.matcher(" Вася ").find());     // true
System.out.println(patternFindRu.matcher("DQWВася12").find());  // true
```

---

Выражение `[а-яА-ЯёЁ]` говорит о поиске символов в указанном диапазоне, думаю это понятно из `a-я` и `А-Я`, но вот `ёЁ` не входит в этот диапазон, поэтому они должны быть указаны. Квадратные скобки (`[]`) обозначают, что нужно искать любой набор символов в них.